# Combine two addresses into one

Tags: solidity, tokens, wallets, addresses

I want Solidity code to define a function *f* that would map two Ethereum addresses A, B into a new address X = *f*(A,B) such that there is nearly zero probability that X is an already taken address (an address of an existing wallet or an address equal to *f*(C,D) where C!=A or D!=B.

I will explain why I want this. I want to create a token COURT that would represent decisions of several courts, each court denoted by an address. A party may endorse or not endorse the court decision. If a court B decision is enforced on a wallet A then *f*(A,B) is considered as a valid reservoir of money, otherwise not.

Comment: Just concatenate them together and hash? But I don't see how that will help... no one will be able to use that address in any meaningful way because no one will have the private key and there will be no way to deploy a contract there. You could send ether there, but you wouldn't be able to get it out.

Comment: `address(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addressA, addressB))))` should do the "concatenate them together and hash" part. But make sure that's going to actually be useful for you.

Comment: @smarx I don't see any trouble here. It is my contract, I can do whatever I want to do with the money (I mean my token COURT, not Ether) stored at this address, for example to transfer it to a wallet of a user that has a private key.

Comment: I mean the address you make up by combining the other two addresses. What are you going to do with address X?

Comment: If it's just internal to your contract, why does it have to be an address at all? Why not just do `mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) courtBalances` and use `courtBalances[addressA][addressB]`?

Comment: @smarx 1. I am going to use a value there. 2. I am going to accept or not transfers from this address depenengly on a list (or rather a tree or like this) of endorsed court decisions. Not yet sure about details. But it seems like having NxM addresses, where N are "real" wallets and M are courts. Not every address can transfer to every other address.

Comment: @smarx 1. I didn't know it works in Solidity. 2. Probably "combining" addresses is more efficient, because I may want to repeat combining say 20 times to create such a thing as a chain of 20 courts each of which endorses the next one.

Comment: @smarx 3. Your way does not work for combining more thatn two addresses like f(f(A,B), C)

Comment: @user19510, is there any chance of collision by using this hash function? My context is to have a *unique* hash from two different addresses which is always the same for the same pair of addresses and always different for any other pair.